# React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "setApprovedDecision" which is neither a React function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the code block through which i am getting error mentioned in title. Do we need to pass down the dispatch to child components. (All my child components are functional components)

````
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export function ApproveModal(props) {
  const setApprovedDecision = () => {
    useDispatch({ type: SUBMIT_DECISION , payload: props.decisionData});
  };
  return (
    <Button buttonStyle="secondary" onClick={setApprovedDecision}>
    Approve
    </Button>
  );
}```
````

Comment: you call ```useDispatch``` to return ```dispatch``` function, which then will be used to dispatch actions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you call `useDispatch` to return `dispatch` function, which then will be used to dispatch actions

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export function ApproveModal(props) {
  const dispatch = useDipatch();
  const setApprovedDecision = () => {
    dispatch({ type: SUBMIT_DECISION , payload: props.decisionData});
  };
  return (
    <Button buttonStyle="secondary" onClick={setApprovedDecision}>
    Approve
    </Button>
  );
}
```